# Set up subdomains for tenants in a Django web app?

Tags: python, django

I have installed django-tenant-schemas for a multitenancy SaaS app I'm trying to build. So far I have managed to create schemas in postgres so each tenant has isolated tables.

If a user goes to my website, e.g www.mydomain.com, and registers by providing a username, password and company (e.g "Joeys Company") - how would I dynamically create a new subdomain for that user, in this case joeyscompany.mydomain.com?

People have mentioned wildcard domains, but not sure how to practically set that up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured it out. For anyone interested, here's the code that automatically creates a tenant upon user registration.

```py
class SignupView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = RegistrationForm()
        return render(request, "accounts/signup.html", {"form": form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            tenant = Client(domain_url=company + ".my-domain.com", schema_name=company, name=company)
            tenant.save()

            with schema_context(tenant.schema_name):
                instance.save()
                redirect = 'http://' + company + '.my-domain.com:8000/accounts/login'
                return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect)
        return render(request, "accounts/signup.html", {"form": form})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be broken down into two smaller sub-questions.

1. How do you specify the domain name for a tenant?

[As described in the docs](https://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use.html#creating-a-tenant), when you create a tenant you use the `domain_url` parameter to associate a domain name with a tenant. So if you make a tenant with `domain_url='tenant.mysite.com'`, and a request comes to your server with the hostname `tenant.mysite.com`, django-tenant-schemas will automatically use the correct database schema for this tenant. This brings us to question two:

2. How do you use DNS to point that subdomain to your application?

You are correct that the easiest way would be to set up a wildcard subdomain. Without going too deep into a DNS lesson, you would have a DNS entry like `*.mysite.com`, where `*` means "anything". This wildcard subdomain would be pointed to the IP address of the server where your application is running. As a result, `anything.mysite.com` will resolve to your server.

The process of setting up a wildcard subdomain will be different depending on your DNS provider. You should consult their documentation for specifics.

Comment: `> ... create a tenant you use the domain_url parameter to associate a domain name with a tenant... use the tenant with domain_url='tenant.mysite.com.'`




This is how I'm doing it right now, manually - however, how would I let users dynamically create their own domain name when they register on the website?

`>The process of setting up a wildcard subdomain will be different depending on your DNS provider. You should consult their documentation for specifics.`


I haven't deployed anything yet, I'm doing it all locally right now

Comment: As far as letting users choose their own subdomain, you can do this in your signup form if you want that functionality. In regards to testing locally, you can use the hosts file on your laptop to point a domain name to your laptop.

Comment: So, then the question remains unanswered - how is this done..

Comment: In regards to question 1, you would need to share your current code (models, forms, views, etc.) for us to help further. In regards to question 2, if you let us know where your DNS is managed, we can try and guide you to the appropriate docs.

Comment: I figured out how to dynamically create the subdomains, but I'm facing another issue now, which is logging the user in - I created a new question for it - found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59436447/redirect-to-tenant-domain-after-signup-with-django-tenants