# Redirect to tenant domain after signup with django-tenants?

Tags: python, django, multi-tenant

I'm using a django-tenants library where each tenant is a separate, isolated postgres schema. The django tenants module does a lot of the heavy lifting and I've got the following code that creates a new tenant each time someone registers. My concern is inside the `schema_context` function which (successfully) creates a user in the newly created schema, but my concern is how I can log that user in and redirect them to `customname.my-domain.com` as seen below:

```
class SignupView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = RegistrationForm()
        return render(request, "accounts/signup.html", {"form": form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            tenant = Client(domain_url=company + ".my-domain.com", schema_name=company, name=company, paid_until="2019-05-10", on_trial=False)
            tenant.save()

            with schema_context(tenant.schema_name):
                instance.save()
                # login(request, instance) - how do I login this user 
                # render.... and redirect them to the newly created domain e.g company.my-domain.com
        return render(request, "accounts/signup.html", {"form": form})
```

Answer (score 1):

I am the maintainer of Django Tenant. As the tenants can take some time to setup I suggest you use celery to create the tenant. Once the tenant is setup I would send the user an email to verify their account / tenant which take them to their tenant.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem this way.

```
subdomain = form.cleaned_data["subdomain"]
host = request.META.get('HTTP_HOST', '')
scheme_url = request.is_secure() and "https" or "http"
url = f"{scheme_url}://{subdomain}.{host}"

return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Comment: Don't understand me wrongly, but I guess English answer is preferred.

Comment: did this work? it doesn't look like this is logging user in