# Django: TypeError in View that I cannot spot

Tags: django

I am making registration form in django. I have followed [Set up subdomains for tenants in a Django web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59430032/set-up-subdomains-for-tenants-in-a-django-web-app) example but I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pierre/Desktop/Django-app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/pierre/Desktop/Django-app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/pierre/Desktop/Django-app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Its been hours and I cannot see where it comes from. I am hoping that a pair of fresh (and more experienced) eyes could see my mistake.

Here are the files I am working with:
models.py

```
class Client(TenantMixin):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    email = models.EmailField(default='')
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    paid_until = models.DateField()
    on_trial = models.BooleanField()
    created_on = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

#


class Domain(DomainMixin):
    pass
```

forms.py

```
class NewClientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100)
    company = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        company = self.clean_date.get('company')

        email_qs = Client.objects.filter(email=email)
        if email_qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "this email is already being used"
            )

        company_qs = Client.objects.filter(company=company)
        if company_qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                'this company name is already identified in our system'
            )
        return email, company
```

view.py

```
class SignupView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = NewClientForm()
        return render(request, "register.html", {'form': form})

    def post(self, request,*args, **kwargs):
        form = NewClientForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            tenant = Client(domain_url='company' + ".inventory4.com", schema_name='company', name= 'name')
            tenant.save()

            with schema_context(tenant.schema_name):
                instance.save()
                redirect = 'http://' + 'company' + '.inventory4.com:8000/login'
                return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect)

        return render(request, "register.html", {'form' : form})
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Likely in the `urls.py`, you forgot to add `.as_view()`.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the right spot in the error?  From what I see, all of the error lines that you show come from /Users/pierre/Desktop/Django-app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/.  But this is a Django location; it is not specific to your site.  You need to look for errors in the log that were generated by your site specifically, so the ones in /Users/pierre/Desktop/Django-app/whatevertheactualwebsitefolderiscalled

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I can't believe that was it! I did not look there....can't believe it, i had to change my model from to form and it works. Well it does not work but it does not give error